# Wildcard in CREATE grant in MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions

MySQL allows the use of wildcards for database names, in order to allow an user to **operate** only on a subset of databases:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `foobar%`.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

Is there a way to do the same for the CREATE grant, to allow (cf. the example above) `user` to **create** only databases whose name starts with `foobar`?

Otherwise said: is the CREATE grant global (i.e. an user with this privilege is allowed to create any database, without limitations) or it can be limited in some way?

Comment: If you are building `foobar1`, `foobar2`, etc., don't.  Bad schema design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Just add the CREATE privilege:

```
GRANT CREATE ON `foobar%`.* TO 'foobaruser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'foobarpass';
```

And just test it:

```
foobaruser$ mysql
mysql> create database `foobar_one`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database `barfoo_one`;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'foobaruser'@'localhost' to database 'barfoo_one'
```

Be aware that you need to escape the `_` (underscore), as it acts like `one character` in the pattern. So «`foobar_`» will match `foobar1` or `foobarZ`.

Comment: Note it does not work at table level, `GRANT CREATE ON 'foo'.'bar%' TO ..` won't work

Comment: @fraff it should. But you've used single quotes `'` instead of backtick `\``. You can even go down to column privileges (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges)

Comment: I tried, with backticks (I don't know how to add backticks in stackexchange comments without ruining indentation) on mysql5.7 but it didn't work. If you manage to do it please let me know, I'm still interested.

Comment: @fraff it should be like this: `GRANT CREATE ON \`foo\`.\`bar%\` TO ...`. To add a backtick you should prefix it by an antislash: `\`\\`\``

Comment: grant is created, I can see it with `show grants for ..` but user still can't create or frop table matching wildcard. I'm using mysql 5.7

Comment: @fraff I would try to set large privileges (full table, all columns), and reduce the privileges one by one to find it out. I don't use such privileges, so I won't help much in the end. Don't forget to use `flush privileges` after each change!